# dd command erros out with larger size than allocated size in VMWARE

Tags: linux, vmware, dd

There is a VM on MAC os which is allocated 100G HDD. When i use dd command to shrink its size by populating the whole disk with 0, it errors out(no empty space left) when the size is increased to 120G instead of 100G. Why it throws the "no space left" exception with 120G but not the allocated 100G?

```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=zero.fill bs=8M
```

When i check the package content, it has 2 vmdk files(why).
      Virtual Disk-000001.vmdk = 96.06G
      Virtual Disk.vmdk = 7.21G

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess.

Probably you've got a shared folder between host and VM and it'll try to fill out the entire machine space.

just 2c.

Need more info to help better